# What does the variable D do inside the while in this Bresenham's line drawing algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, bresenham

I've found this [Generalized Bresenham's Line Drawing Algorithm](https://web.archive.org/web/20040929015146/https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2003/cmsc427/bresenham.html) and I'm having a hard time understanding what the `while` is doing here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

the code:

```
#define sign(x) ((x > 0)? 1 : ((x < 0)? -1: 0))

x = x1; 
y = y1;
dx = abs(x2 - x1); 
dy = abs(y2 - y1);
s1 = sign(x2 - x1); 
s2 = sign(y2 - y1);
swap = 0;

if (dy > dx) {
    temp = dx;
    dx = dy;
    dy = temp;
    swap = 1;
}

D = 2*dy - dx;
for (i = 0; i < dx; i++) {
    display_pixel (x, y); 
    while (D >= 0) { 
        D = D - 2*dx;
        if (swap)
            x += s1;
        else
            y += s2;
    } 
    D = D + 2*dy;
    if (swap)
        y += s2;
    else
        x += s1; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>`D` is the scaled distance from the line to the candidate `x, y` coordinate.</strike>

Better: `D` is scaled  *difference* of the distance from the line to  the candidates `x+1, y+0` and `x+1, y+1`.

That is, as `x` increments, the sign of `D` indicates should the closer `y` increment by 0 or 1?

(The role of `x, y` interchanges depending on which octant the algorithm is applied.)

---

I expected `while (D >= 0) {` as `if (D >= 0) {`.  [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#Algorithm)

---

Note that OP's code is subject to overflow in `abs(x2 - x1)` and `2*dy - dx`.  Alternates exist that do not rely on wider math.

Comment: What do you mean by your last paragraph?

Comment: Consider `x2== INT_MAX, x1 == -1`, then `x2 - x1` overflows.  `dy` can readily be near `INT_MAX`, then `2*dy` overflows.  A robust version of the  algorithm would handle all `int` and is doable without resorting to wider types.

Comment: Do you know of a better version of this algorithm that you can point me to?

Comment: @MiguelP I have one, perhaps I'll post later.